# Transition Probability Matrix calculation for sentences

Tags: java, similarity, trigonometry, tf-idf

I have sentences stored as strings extracted from a document. I want to apply standard cosine similarity to sentences. How do i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you already have the  [formula on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Definition). Each of the `Ai` is a word so first you need to compute the frequency of words in your document . You need to be able to create a map of word occurrences. Then you represent each sentences by a vector of words and you can apply the formula.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read about [Term-Document matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix)

Then, go for the Cosine calculation using [Cosine Similarity calculator](http://appliedsoftwaredesign.com/cosineSimilarityCalculator.php)

If you are interested in text mining, then go for [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) and finally [Latent Semantic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis)